# Cauchy random variable question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If X is a Cauchy random variable it has the density function as follows:

$f_X(x):= \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(x-\Theta)^2 }$ con $x \in R$ e $- \Theta<x<\Theta$

I have to demostrate that the random variable $Y=\frac{1}{X}$ is a Cauchy random variable too.

$$F_Y (a)=P(Y<a)=P(\frac{1}{X}<a)=P(X>\frac{1}{a})=1-F_x(\frac{1}{a})=1- \int_{- \infty}^{\frac{1}{a}} \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(x-\Theta)^2 }\, dx=1-\frac{1}{\pi} *[arctg(x- \Theta)]_{- \infty}^{\frac{1}{a}} =1-\frac{1}{\pi} *[arctg(\frac{1}{a} - \Theta)-(-\frac{\pi}{2}) ]=1-\frac{1}{\pi} *(\frac{\pi}{2}+arctg(\frac{1}{a} - \Theta) )=1-\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{\pi}*arctg(\frac{1}{a} - \Theta )=\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{\pi}*arctg(\frac{1}{a} - \Theta )$$

Throught the identity $\frac{\pi}{2}=\arctan (x)+\arctan (\frac{1}{x})$.

I can write the previous identity in
$$F_Y (a)=
\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\arctan(\frac{x}{1-x*\theta})$$
Then I can derivate $F_Y (a)$ to find $f_Y (a)$

$$f_Y (a)=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{(1- \Theta*x)^2}}$$p
Now I don't know how to continue
can someone help me if I have done some mistakes?

Comment: When I differentiated $arctan(1/x-\theta)$ I get a different answer to you. so maybe check that bit.

Comment: $P(Y<a)\ne P(X>1/a)$...

Comment: @d.k.o. $Y<a  \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{X}<a \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{a}<X \Rightarrow  X>\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: The cdf you computed is wrong. Just look at it's graph for some fixed $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the final steps: all is perfect up to

$$F_Y (a)=
\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\arctan(\frac{x}{1-x*\theta})$$

"Then I can derivate $F_Y (a)$ to find $f_Y (a)$" also ok, only you have to set $x\to 1/a$ before you differentiate with respect to $a$.

Then you`ll get

$$f_{Y}(a) = \frac {1}{\pi} \frac{1}{a^2 \left(\theta ^2+1\right)-2 a \theta +1}\tag{1}$$

In order to identify this as a Cauchy distribution we write the pdf of a Cauchy distribution in $t$ with parameters $u$ and $v$ in the form

$$f_{C}(u,v,t)=\frac{1}{\pi  \left(\frac{(t-u)^2}{v}+v\right)}$$

the original parameters were

$$\left\{u\to \theta, v\to 1, t\to x\right\}$$

and after the transformation we have found in $(1)$ a Cauchy distribution with the parameters

$$\left\{u\to \frac{\theta }{\theta ^2+1},v\to \frac{1}{\theta ^2+1}, t\to a\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(x)=x^{-1}$. Then
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=f_X(x)(h^{-1}(y))\times\left\lvert \frac{dh^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right\rvert \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\times\frac{1}{1+(1/y-\theta)^2}\times\frac{1}{y^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\times\frac{1}{\gamma\left(1+[\gamma^{-1}(y-\tau)]^2\right)},
\end{align}
where $\gamma\equiv (1+\theta^2)^{-1}$ and $\tau\equiv\gamma\cdot\theta$.

---

Alternatively (assume for simplicity that $\theta=0$), for $y>0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(Y\le y)=\mathsf{P}(X\le 0)+\mathsf{P}(X\ge y^{-1})=1-\frac{\arctan(y^{-1})}{\pi}
$$
and for $y\le 0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(Y\le y)=\mathsf{P}(y^{-1}\le X\le 0)=-\frac{\arctan(y^{-1})}{\pi}.
$$
Thus,
$$
f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\times \frac{1}{1+y^2}
$$

Comment: sorry but I can't understand, can you help me with my integral?

Comment: @d.k.o. The third line is wrong, the result at the end as well.